# JAVA - Fixed length for loop giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

Hey I don't know why but this loop is not working and giving me same error every time. If you know the fix please answer it down. And I am not able fix the issue.

**Here is my loop**

```
double angle = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++, angle += 3) {
    int x = (int) Math.ceil(i * 8.5);
    int t = ((byte) (-Math.abs(bytes[x]) + 128))
            * (canvas.getHeight() / 4) / 128;

    points[i * 4] = (float) (getWidth() / 2
            + radius
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));

    points[i * 4 + 1] = (float) (getHeight() / 2
             + radius
             * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));

    points[i * 4 + 2] = (float) (getWidth() / 2
            + (radius + t)
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));

    points[i * 4 + 3] = (float) (getHeight() / 2
            + (radius + t)
            * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));
}
```

**Here is my error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: app.androidgrid.faysr, PID: 19297

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=128; index=128
     at app.androidgrid.faysr.visualizer.view.CircleBarVisualizer.onDraw(CircleBarVisualizer.java:94)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17096)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16078)
```

I also tried changing **120** to **128** and **i < 120** to **i <= 120** but it's not

**Here is my java class**

```
public class CircleBarVisualizer extends BaseVisualizer {
private float[] points;
private Paint circlePaint;
private int radius;

public CircleBarVisualizer(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CircleBarVisualizer(Context context,
                           @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CircleBarVisualizer(Context context,
                           @Nullable AttributeSet attrs,
                           int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void init() {
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    radius = -1;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (radius == -1) {
        radius = getHeight() < getWidth() ? getHeight() : getWidth();
        radius = (int) (radius * 0.65 / 2);
        double circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) (circumference / 120));
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    }
    circlePaint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, radius, circlePaint);
    if (bytes != null) {
        if (points == null || points.length < bytes.length * 4) {
            points = new float[bytes.length * 4];
        }
        double angle = 0;

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++, angle += 3) {
                int x = (int) Math.ceil(i * 8.5);
                int t = ((byte) (-Math.abs(bytes[x]) + 128))
                        * (canvas.getHeight() / 4) / 128;

                points[i * 4] = (float) (getWidth() / 2
                        + radius
                        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));

                points[i * 4 + 1] = (float) (getHeight() / 2
                        + radius
                        * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));

                points[i * 4 + 2] = (float) (getWidth() / 2
                        + (radius + t)
                        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));

                points[i * 4 + 3] = (float) (getHeight() / 2
                        + (radius + t)
                        * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        canvas.drawLines(points, paint);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}}
```

I am also try-catch so, it won't crash the app, but the result is not as I am excepting.

Comment: The for loop iterates i from 0 to 119, but then the code uses multiples of i (`i * 4...`) to adress elements in the `points` array that is only 128 elements long (as the exception says).

Comment: You're accessing two arrays: `points[]` and `bytes[]`. The latter is indexed by `x` which is `ceil(i * 8.5)`. With `i == 15` the value of `x`will be 128 (`ceil(127.5)`) and also fits to your error message.  Hence this could be a problem as well.

Comment: one of your arrays has a  length of 128, so your max index is 127, since you're zero indexed.  your loop appears to result in you trying to access an element larger than the array size. try commenting out each array element call and see which one is triggering the error.  your `Math.ceil(i * 8.5)` call is going to hit  128 when `i=15`

Comment: @AnkitSuda make sure you upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `i = 0 ... 120`, on the final iteration of your loop the following statement:

```
points[i * 4 + 3]
```

would be trying to access the 479th element of an array (`(119 * 4) + 3 = 479`) that only contains 128 elements.

In order to fill your array, you want `i < 31` because `(31 * 4) + 3 = 127`.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=128; index=128` 
-> this means you are trying to access the 129th element of an array only containing 128 elements.

Remember, in Java arrays are 0 based, so the valid indices in your case vary from 0 to 127

Comment: But the loop should be end at 120

Comment: i ends at 120, but you use i * 4 and such as indices. when i is 100, that means you would try to get the 400 index. But you're not showing enough of your code for us to know for sure which line causes the problem

Comment: Ok wait I am updating the code.

Comment: assuming that CircleBarVisualizer is a class you made, check line 94, that's where it happens.

Comment: But the class ends at 89 :P

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: if it ends at 89, you are running a version compiled before you deleted lines.  I didn't invent the '94' line, I copied it from the error method you posted

Comment: Yes, I removed some comments from the code.

Comment: so, compile and run it again, and check the (new) error message what line to check

Comment: Same error but this time it says line no. 61 which is                     int x = (int) Math.ceil(i * 8.5);

Comment: that line can not possible throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, because there is no array involved there.

Answer (score 0):

Even you have `for` loop, which iterate for index `0` to `120`, but inside your `for` loop you are trying to access different index (`i * 4`, `i * 4 +` etc), which is causing actual issue.

Imagine, you have `points` array of `2` size. Now, on first iteration, `i` would be `0`, but you would be trying to access element `i * 4 + 3`, which would be equivalent to `3`. But, ***`points` array size is 2.***

Since, you are trying to access element `i * 4 + 3` (which would be higher end in each iteration). I would suggest to change your `for` loop to something to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (if array size is `120`)

```
 for (int i = 0; (i * 4 + 3) < 120; i++, angle += 3) {
```

Answer (score -1):

You must review the size of the "points" array. Considering your code, its size should be at least (119 * 4 +3), i.e. 479.

"points" array size is 4 * "bytes" array size, but your code doesn't show what is the "bytes" array size; probably something defined in the ancestor class.